# How to embed an AMP page in my website?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I'm working on a web app to aggregate news. I want to show amp enabled pages in the same window as google search result shows on mobile devices.

I have not found a single document on how to embed an amp page on our website.

I tried these two links-

[PolyerLab](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/amp-viewer) - This one does not load pages because of CORS is disabled by chrome so couldnt test it further, (I wonder does it ignore the CORS restriction for google.com?)

[AMP by Example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/viewer.html) - viewer from official ampproject website, files `amp-viewer-host.max.js` and `viewer-integr-messaging.js` required for `viewer.html' are missing from the git repository.

There is no question on stackoverflow as well on this. Has anyone implemented something like this already? Help much appreciated!

Comment: what about iframes?

Comment: Doesnt always work, eg it worked for http://m.economictimes.com/news/defence/india-pakistan-face-off-at-international-court-of-justice-over-kulbhushan-jadhav/amp_articleshow/58687084.cms but does not work for http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/we-want-india-in-peace-process-says-palestine-president-mahmoud-abbas/article18459281.ece/amp/

Answer (score 3):

The [example in the official repository](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/viewer.html) is the best way to get started with implementing your own AMP viewer. You get `amp-viewer-host.max.js` when you [build the AMP runtime locally](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/contributing/getting-started-quick.md). It's located in: `dist/v0/examples/amp-viewer-host.max.js` after running `gulp build`. The other file `viewer-integr-messaging.js` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the actual site page which has amphtml & url of amp page. Just load that url in iframe.
example :
site page :

```
 www.example.com/product_page it has <link rel="amphtml" href="www.example.com/product_page_amp-version.html"> in its <head>
to embed use 
<iframe src="www.example.com/product_page_amp-version.html"></iframe>
```